# JSch Mainframe To Windows SFTP Issue

Tags: java, sftp, jsch

I'm using JCraft's JSch library to support SFTP transfers.
Everything works when I do an SFTP transfer from a Windows machine to another Windows machine. However, when I try to do a transfer from a z/OS system to a Windows machine I get the following error:

```
com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Session.connect:
java.security.SignatureException : 
Signature length not correct: got 143 but was expecting 128
        at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:565)
        at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:183)
        at com.gt.mfdeploy.lib.GTSFTP.xferFile(GTSFTP.java:24)
        at com.gt.mfdeploy.request.MFDeploy.<init>(MFDeploy.java:89)
        at com.gt.mfdeploy.request.MFDeploy.main(MFDeploy.java:174)
```

Any help on resolving this would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks,
Marc

Comment: What version of jsch are you using there?

Comment: I'm using version 1.55